# allow post requests in django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, http-post

I am creating a simple rest api using django REST framework. I have successfully got the response by sending GET request to the api but since I want to send POST request, the django rest framework doesn't allow POST request by default.

As in image(below) only GET,HEAD, OPTIONS are allowed but not the POST request 
[image]

The GET and POST methods inside of views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from profiles_api import serializers
from rest_framework import status
# Create your views here.


class HelloApiView(APIView):
    """Test APIView"""

    #Here we are telling django that the serializer class for this apiViewClass is serializer.HelloSerializer class
    serializer_class = serializers.HelloSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
    """Retruns a list of APIViews features."""

    an_apiview = [
        'Uses HTTP methods as fucntion (get, post, patch, put, delete)',
        'It is similar to a traditional Django view',
        'Gives you the most of the control over your logic',
        'Is mapped manually to URLs'
    ]

    #The response must be as dictionary which will be shown in json as response
    return Response({'message': 'Hello!', 'an_apiview': an_apiview})

    def post(self,request):
        """Create a hello message with our name"""

        serializer = serializer.HelloSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            name = serializer.data.get('name')
            message = 'Hello! {0}'.format(name)
            return Response({'message':message})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

> How to allow POST requests in django REST framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the code was, you have added the `def post()` after the `return` statement.
To solve, just correct your `indentation` level as below,

```
class HelloApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response()

    def post(self, request):
        return Response()
```